# Intel HD4000 driver not working in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, display-settings

I have an issue with Intel HD4000 drivers on my Windows 7 installation.

A few days ago I tried to update to the latest version of this driver and after a restart it got stuck with the default Windows VGAsave driver.

In device manager the driver is installed correctly, but it is not working. the currently installed driver is the one downloaded by Windows Update, but no other driver will work. They only show blank adapter names in display settings, like "1. (Default Monitor) on \blank\".

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the adapter in device manager, but no luck.

I think it might be an issue with Virtu MPV I installed a few months ago.

Comment: Have you tried going to the intel site and download the latest driver from there?

Comment: yes, the problem appeared when i tried to update to 3071 driver , now i have installed 2932 driver from windows update . anyway, same results on any driver.

Comment: i tried to attach a picture , but i'm newbie here and i cannot

Comment: If you have a Restore Point you could roll back to there. Otherwise I would suggest reinstalling the latest Intel driver (rather than the adapter). I've had times where that has cleaned up things.

Comment: i have system restore disabled. i also reinstalled all versions of hd4000 drivers, no result :( .

Comment: Looks like there is a older version on the Intel site 15.28.12.64.2932  that you could try.

Comment: like you can see in my upper comments i now have 2932 installed, and i also tried all other drivers. please understand that it's a windows bug and not an intel driver issue. i have read on other forums about users who had same issues and seemed to be an windows registry corruption

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it. As a last solution, I opened `regedit` and deleted all entries containing 'hd graphics'.

After a reboot and installing the Intel 3071 drivers again, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by updating the "PCI Bus" driver from the Intel one with the Microsoft one.